# Input dispatching timed out error on Xamarin App Android

Tags: android, xamarin, samsung-mobile, android-anr-dialog

I have a problem with Xamarin Android.

Several Android users using my app are getting ANR error, 9/10 on Samsung devices. I've tryed to replicate the problem on our devices with no success (Samsung S9 and A3 2016).

The homepage page seems work correctly; it use a do while statement but i don't think is influent (see below code).
The error occurs during the login phase while performing some http request.

**Homepage animation:**

```
private async Task AnimazioneTiles()
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    foreach (VMTileWelcome tile in tilesWelcome)
                    {

                        tileImage.Source = tile.ImageSource;
                        tileTitle.Text = tile.Title;
                        tileSubTitile.Text = tile.SubTitle;

                        await stackContenitoreTiles.FadeTo(1, 400, Easing.Linear);
                        await Task.Delay(5000);
                        await stackContenitoreTiles.FadeTo(0, 400, Easing.Linear);
                        await Task.Delay(500);

                    }

                }
                while (true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Errore animazione! {ex}");
            }
        }
```

**Http requests:**

```
HttpOperationResponse<t> result = await Task.Run(async () => await this.PostAsync<t>(endPoint, content));
```

**ANR Google Console:**

Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 14. Wait queue head age: 61840.6ms.)

md5b5fc6e3de8ade6adb016b96a6a1d3645.MainActivity

```
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
      | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x773c4e18 self=0x773eccba00
      | sysTid=11111 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x774361cab0
      | state=S schedstat=( 40042176353 355926648 12143 ) utm=3900 stm=104 core=4 HZ=100
      | stack=0x7fd48ce000-0x7fd48d0000 stackSize=8MB
      | held mutexes=
      #00  pc 000000000001bf6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
      #01  pc 00000000000e8890  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+160)
      #02  pc 000000000034aa64  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI23CallStaticObjectMethodAEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+292)
      #03  pc 000000000000b4d0  /data/app/it.tisviluppo.fpcu-1/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so (java_interop_jnienv_call_static_object_method_a+40)
      at md58432a647068b097f9637064b8985a5e0.NavigationPageRenderer.n_onAttachedToWindow (Native method)
      at md58432a647068b097f9637064b8985a5e0.NavigationPageRenderer.onAttachedToWindow (NavigationPageRenderer.java:49)
      at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:16879)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3129)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3136)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner (ViewGroup.java:4675)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4477)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4417)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4390)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1425)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1750)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1819)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:797)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManager.java:2590)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2377)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:2332)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2239)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:700)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6823)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1563)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Someone had the same problems with xamarin ?

Comment: This question is ambiguous, please add the `StackTrace`?

Comment: I cannot get it from Google Play Console and i've not been able of replicate that on my devices :( (sorry for bad english)

Comment: If your application crashes Google Play console has all the stack trace details, to be very honest without it you are doomed, you will probably need a century to understand the issue, and if you are not able to reproduce this on debugging maybe download the app from the store and check then if this happens there!

Comment: I've already test the release version from the store as well

Comment: SO even that works for you?

Comment: No, i can't replicate the problem. It's few months that we are searching for solutions. The problem ,seems for us, started since an update of Xamarin Forms but we can't be sure.

Comment: Your application was already on the Playstore right a change in Xamarin Forms cannot affect something that was already present there can it?

Comment: Yes, we've published 2-3 updates to try to resolve the problem but we have no idea what is happening

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the energy saving mode in Samsungs devices!

Comment: Can you share some more information? How the energy saving mode affects the app? How you solved the problem?